# How do I add Eclipse or GitEye to Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop Favourites list?

Tags: java, favorites

How do I add Eclipse or GitEye to Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop Favourites list?

When I run them and right-click on them in Favourites list, the only options are "All Windows" and "Quit" options. I have successfully added other programs (but can't re-arrange - another issue).

The two programs I'm trying to add might be both java programs.

Answer (score 2):

First please open terminal and go to your home directory.

After that create desktop file inside with this command:

`nano .local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`

inside add something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse IDE
Type=Application
Exec=/home/your_Path_To_Eclipse/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/your_Path_To_Eclipse/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

After that save the file and search Eclipse inside applications. If you find it in the results press on the icon right mouse button Add to Favorites.

Now should appear inside your favorite list.

Good Luck!